# jquery validation on multiple dynamically generated fields (using nested attributes in rails 3.1)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

I'm using the jquery validation plugin to validate a form for my rails application. 
The form allows the user to add items dynamically to the form's main object's **has_many** relationship. 
My problem is, how can I validate each of those items using the jQuery validation plugin. For instance a description text field for the associated object.

The field's names in the form that are dynamically added look like:
project[tickets_attributes][0][description]

where project is the main object, **tickets_attributes** are the attributes association with my has_many association, 
the `0 (or association object id)` unique and description is the name of the attribute in my **has_many** association.

Answer (score 0):

when you add the event on **click button "send"** for example you need to use `.live()` instead of `.click()` or `.bind()`.

`.live()` will accept all your dynamic inputs.

**Update**

<strike>`.live()`</strike> is now deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and has been removed on 1.9. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `.delegate()`, this will let you attach event handlers to any items that maybe dynamically generated. 
in my example below, any item with the class "dynamic-item"

example something like

```
$form.delegate(".dynamic-item", "onChange", validate)
```

this will fire off the validate function anytime one of your dynamic elements is changed, and you can use this to call the validator